# Spark & MapR DB Connections

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapr

I am new to MapR distribution. I need read and write operations on MapR DB using Spark with Scala. But I am not finding the exact jar to do these operations.

But in

```
https://mapr.com/docs/home/Spark/WorkingwithComplexJSONDocTypes.html
```

they mentioned as

```
import com.mapr.db.spark._

val userprofilesRDD = sc.loadFromMapRDB("/tmp/user_profiles")
```

to load the data from MapRDB.

But my question is where this package(com.mapr.db.spark._) is available. To download this package I am not finding the correct source(in maven repository also).

Please guide me the correct approach to do these tasks. I know these all are basic operations. As I am new to this, unable to find do this.

Version details:

MapR  : 6.0.1-mapr

Spark : 2.2.1

Scala : 2.11.8

Gradle : 3.5

Please mention which artifact Id I need to use to do these operations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Those classes are in the mapr-spark-.rpm of the MapR Expansion Pack (MEP) release for whatever version you are running.  The classes you mention are in the maprdb-spark-.jar in that RPM.  Upon installation of the mapr-spark RPM, you'd find the jar in the /opt/mapr/spark/spark-/jars directory.